# Remove 'Is Null' and 'Is Not Null' from Kendo Filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm not sure if this is a new addition to the Kendo UI library or not but I've never seen these filters before. On all of the text columns in my grids I now have the filters `Is Null`, `Is Not Null`, `Is Empty`, and `Is Not Empty`. These filters are useless for me though as I'm never going to return empty or null results to the grid.

I tried looking through the documentation but couldn't find anyway to remove just these filters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are new features introduced recently.  As far as I know, you can't tell the grid to ignore a specific operator, but you can do the opposite by telling the grid which operator could be used by the user using the the buil-it [filterable-operators](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-filterable.operators):

So if you want to allow the user to use only the Equal and Not Equal operators, you would write something like this:

```
filterable: {
    operators: {
        string: {
            eq: "Is equal to",
            neq: "Is not equal to"
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the list of operators is based on the column's type.  The example above handle only the operator for the string column.  You may have to apply the same logic for the other column's type.

Comment: That was what I was thinking. Thanks for the clarification!